# Tried to fix wifi issue while Bluetooth On now wifi doesn't work even with Bluetooth disabled

Tags: intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I'm new to Linux just installed it. I realized that when I try to connect my Bluetooth earphones to my computer the wifi goes off. I searched and found some propositions and since I've typed those two lines of codes, my computer keeps attempting to connect to the wifi even with Bluetooth off.
Here are the code lines that I entered
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have removed iwlwifi module.

Suggestions are to re-install the kernel.

Open root terminal:
sudo -H gnome-terminal

Reinstall kernel:
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image-3.19.0-26-generic

You may need to replace the image version with your image version

reboot

Comment: Today when I started to try your solution I found out the wifi back and working. Should I remove install the kernel even so? Won't I lose my datas?

Comment: Yes you should always backup your data...just because.  No keep the code for the future